# CPU usage goes high in Asp.Net MVC application while longer process run by other utility

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, console

I have one application which is developed in ASP .NET MVC 3 which using a SQL server database.

Apart from this, I have one console application which calls an external web service and update the same database with the information and business rules. (Basically we iterate the records from Web service and process the business rule and update the same database), we have configured the console application with Windows scheduler to process it periodically.

*The problem is*, when my Console application runs periodically, it uses the 100% CPU usage (because we're getting more than 2000 records from web service), and because of that my current MVC application is gets haging OR sometime works very very slow because both application are configured on same windows server.

Could anybody please do let me know that How would I resolve this problem where I want both the things on same server because I have central database used by both application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given any detail that anyone can really provide resolution, so I'll simply suggest how I would approach it.

First, I would review the database schema with a DBA to make sure there aren't things like table locks (or if there are, come up with strategies to compensate for them).  I would then use the SQL Server profiler to see where (or if) there are any bottle necks in SQL server while these things are running.  I would then profile the console application to make sure it's not doing something it doesn't need to be doing. I might even consider profiling the web site to see if there's anything in there that might be contributing to slowness.

After that, I would figure out how to get rid of the Console application and work its functionality into the site.  Spawning another application on a given web request is not scalable.  More than a couple of those come in at once and you've got the potential to bog the server down very easily.